# C# XMl || XmlNode.AppendChild

Tags: c#, xml

Требуется к указанному узлу добавить дочерний узел.
Исключений не возникает, но файл `data.xml` не содержит подключенный узел.
Код:

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(openFileDialog1.FileName);    

while (reader.Read())
{
    if(textBox1.Text == reader.Name)
    {
        XmlNode root = doc.ReadNode(reader);
        XmlElement elem = doc.CreateElement("test_node");
        elem.InnerText = "test_text";

        root.AppendChild(elem);

        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.Indent = true;
        XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(path +"\\data.xml", settings);

        doc.Save(writer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Уточняю. Сам файл data.xml создается, но его структура совпадает с структурой doc, то есть новый узел не отображается

Comment: Метод `ReadNode` _создаёт_ новый узел. Но он не вставлен в дерево DOM! Либо добавляйте его с помощью `AppendChild`, либо получайте с помощью `SelectSingleNode`, например.

Comment: Уберите одновременное использование `XmlTextReader` и `XmlDocument`. Используйте что-то одно. А лучше всего, возьмите LinqToXml - классы `XDocument`/`XElement`.

Comment: Саша, ты лучший :-*